# unable to install mkl mkl-service using conda in docker

Tags: python, linux, docker, anaconda, conda

I have docker file like below:

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3

RUN conda update -n base -c defaults conda
RUN conda create -c conda-forge -n pymc3_env pymc3 numpy theano-pymc mkl mkl-service

COPY ./src /app

WORKDIR /app

CMD ["conda", "run", "-n", "pymc3_env", "python", "ma.py"]
```

I get the following error:

```
------                                                                                                                                          
 > [3/5] RUN conda create -c conda-forge -n pymc3_env pymc3 numpy theano-pymc mkl mkl-service:                                                  
#0 0.400 Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... done                                                                
#0 9.148 Solving environment: ...working... failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.              
#0 9.149 Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done                                                                        
#0 45.81 Solving environment: ...working... failed                                                                                              
#0 45.82 
#0 45.82 PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
#0 45.82 
#0 45.82   - mkl-service
#0 45.82   - mkl
#0 45.82 
#0 45.82 Current channels:
#0 45.82 
#0 45.82   - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-aarch64
#0 45.82   - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
#0 45.82   - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-aarch64
#0 45.82   - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
#0 45.82   - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-aarch64
#0 45.82   - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
#0 45.82 
#0 45.82 To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
#0 45.82 looking for, navigate to
#0 45.82 
#0 45.82     https://anaconda.org
#0 45.82 
#0 45.82 and use the search bar at the top of the page.
#0 45.82 
#0 45.82 
------
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c conda create -c conda-forge -n pymc3_env pymc3 numpy theano-pymc mkl mkl-service]: exit code: 1
```

Can anybody help me to understand why conda could not find `mkl` and `mkl-service` in `conda-forge` channel and what do I need to resolve this?

I am using macos as a host, if it is any concern.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MKL only works for `x86_64`, that is the Docker image must use the platform `linux/amd64`. So, either specify `--platform=linux/amd64` in the `build` command line or in the `FROM`.